# Documents about C language specs

Tags: c, specifications

I'm wondering about the difference between what is defined by the several standards of the C language and the things that every compilers implements in a different way from the others, i want to really understand what the official specs of the C language are: there are some official docs?

I'm looking for technical stuff, not a thread on the internet, some good pdfs maybe; something that can describe everything happens with the memory management, the allocation, the lenght and the encoding of the variables, etc etc ...

I have the official manual from K&R but it's not really about what i am interested to, it's more on the "programmer side" i want something more technical and affermative.

PS
the C language have an official website for reference?

Comment: For where to get the standards, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check this](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/The_C_Standard)

"Obtaining the Standard

Neither the Standard nor its amendments are available free of charge, although its drafts, rationales, technical corrigenda (TCs) and defect report responses are.
The Standard can be purchased in hardcopy and/or downloadable digital format from national affiliates as described on the WG14 website. Two such national bodies are ANSI - through its eStandards Store - and SAI Global (originally Standards Australia) which sells all of the ISO C Standard publications. One international source is Techstreet.
Listed below are direct links to pages for purchase or free download of the Standard, its TCs, amendments, drafts, rationales and defect report responses for each version of the Standard. The set of documents is comprehensive whereas the list of sources obviously is not."

Comment: Now that I know this it's funny to know that linux was written in a language of which the specs are non-free.

Comment: @nightcracker: It's even more ironic to read books teaching you C but failing to cover or decently explain some important topics (type conversions/promotions, overflows, implementation-specific/defined and undefined behavior, etc). As if those who write these books don't even know enough C, let alone the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to add this as a comment but the URL would not take.

Try: http://www.deitel.com/Default.aspx?tabid=204  for details on C. I also suggest you dig up GNU's big document on C as they do some things differently and it can be important to understand GNUs way of doing things. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/.